# optical mark reader (omr) in php

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am working on a project (OMR) in PHP. i have google it but did not find any solution.

now my question is that what is the best way of comparing two images to get the result.

[image]

Comment: are the images always going to be exact in dimensions and positioning of items?

Comment: no, the image is scanned and then upload for comparison.  the change in dimensions and position is possible

Comment: OpenCV is a common library for image processing, you may want to look into https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP.  I've not done this in PHP, but worked with it in Java and it's quite powerful in recognition.

Comment: ok thanks but I need to know how it compares exactly and how we get the marks comparison

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a PHP package that uses ImageMagick to read markup on images.

Maybe that can help you https://github.com/jansenfelipe/omr